# do Operators instead of a whole Subscriber

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

It's quite appealing to use `Action`(s) instead of a whole `Subscriber` when you only need `OnNext()` merely because it's more readable. But of course, errors happen and if you only use `Action1` you'll get an `Exception` in your app. `do` [operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) can be of help here. I'm only concerned these two approaches are fully the same, please confirm or disconfirm. Any pitfalls?

The first approach:

```
Observable
        .just(readFromDatabase())
        .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
          @Override public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            // handle error
          }
        }).subscribe(new Action1<SomeData>() {
          @Override public void call(SomeData someData) {
            // react!
          }
    });
```

The second approach:

```
Observable
        .just(readFromDatabase())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<SomeData>() {
          @Override public void onCompleted() {
            // do nothing
          }

          @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // handle error
          }

          @Override public void onNext(SomeData someData) {
            // react!
          }
        });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches aren't quite the same, and you're going to get some surprises out of the first:

First surprise will be that `doOnError` doesn't consume the error, but only performs some action on it. Consequently, in your case if the stream generates an error, it'll go through your `doOnError` code, and right after that trigger an `OnErrorNotImplementedException`, exactly as if the `doOnError` step wasn't there.

Let's say you realize that, and add an empty error handler to your subscribe call:

```
Observable
    .just(readFromDatabase())
    .doOnError(...)
    .subscribe(..., error -> { /* already handled */ } );
```

Then you can meet the next subtle difference. `do*` blocks are considered part of the stream, which means that any uncatched exception in the block will result in a stream error (as opposed with exceptions thrown in 'onNext/OnError/onComplete' blocks, which get either ignored or immediately thrown, canceling the subscription on their way).

So in the above sample, if we say your database read triggers a stream error `A`, which gets passed to the `doOnError` block, which throws an exception `B`, then the (empty) subscription error handler we added will receive `B` (and only `B`).

The later difference isn't very concerning for `doOnError` (because anyway the stream gets terminated), but can be pretty surprising when occuring in `doOnNext`, where an exception has a very different behavior than the same exception thrown in subscribe `onNext` block (error'ed stream versus implicitly canceled stream).

Comment: Actually, doOnError could report both exceptions by combining them into a CompositeException. I'll file a PR for it.

Comment: It could, but I find the current behavior ok, as it's similar to imperative catch blocks (like if you throw `B` when catching `A`, only `B` is thrown, up to you to make it a `CompositeException` - or not), it also allows to _alter_ a stream error, though I don't know if this has real uses (and anyway can be achieved with `onErrorResumeNext(Obs.Throw(...))`).

Comment: Awesome you saved me a lot of time.
I mapped exception thrown from doOnError handler and then realized it is not catched but didn't know how to work around with CompositeException. Your proposition worked great, thanks.