# How do I access the main thread after a background thread completes in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have an observable that does some IO processing on the background thread:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<File>() {

        @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super File> subscriber) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                    URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

                    File saveDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                    File downloadedFile = new File(saveDir, filename);
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
```

After the io work is done, I want to hide the progressBar.  Of course I cannot do this inside call(Subscriber) of my anonymous class because accessing ui elements from the io thread will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the common pattern for this is `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`. Using lambdas for brevity:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<File()...)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .doOnCompleted(() -> progressBar.setVisibility(invisible))
  .subscribe(file -> {}, error -> reportError(error));
```

If you want to hide the progress bar on completion or error then you could replace `.doOnCompleted` with `.doOnTerminate`.

A quick warning that you should do your damndest to avoid `Observable.create` because of backpressure for starters.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have `OnErrorNotImplementedException` if an exception happens.

Comment: Because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889008/do-operators-instead-of-a-whole-subscriber

Comment: oh yeah true. Lazy me. I'll chuck the appropriate lambdas in the subscribe. Thanks

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't work because the doOnCompleted action is never hit after the call action defined in Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<FIle>()

Comment: Do you call subscriber.onCompleted() from your OnSubscribe?

Comment: @DaveMoten no, that interface doesn't support onComplete, only next(): http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.OnSubscribe.html  Also all these callbacks take place on the io thread so accessing the ui would throw a runtime exception

Comment: OnSubscribe has a single method call that expects a Subscriber. You make calls to the subscriber parameter to emit onNext, onError or onCompleted events. Can you show us your OnSubscribe implementation so we can sort it out?